# Python 3.2 split the string values in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list like below:

```
rawinput = ['corp\\asre', 'corp\\banjar', 'corp\\bicknk', 'corp\\daniele']
```

I want to be able to do

```
users = []
users = rawinput.split(",")
print(users)
```

How do I do this in Python 3.2? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have,

`rawinput = ['corp\\asre', 'corp\\banjar', 'corp\\bicknk', 'corp\\daniele']`

is a list of strings already. You can just iterate through it as a list. You don't need to split anything.

If you had something like this,

`rawinput = "corp\\asre, corp\\banjar, corp\\bicknk, corp\\daniele"`

`rawinput.split(',')` would return the above list.

Answer (score 2):

`split()` is applied on string, in return it gives you a list[] which contains the substring as elements in order of the parent string.

In your case:

```
input = "corp\\asre, corp\\banjar, corp\\bicknk, corp\\daniele"
input.split(',')
```

will return
`['corp\\asre', 'corp\\banjar', 'corp\\bicknk', 'corp\\daniele']`